# mysql php variable nested

Tags: php, mysql, nested

My mysql select statement out put a string like this for me:

```
$domain = "test.com";
$time = "12345";

echo $result;
```

outputs below:

```
I just pull this from $domain from $time
```

I don't know what else I need to do for my mysql select statement to show it properly when echoing... I'm trying to make it show the following:

```
I just pull this from test.com from 12345
```

any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you have error when you echo. The problem is in your code. please send some more code so that I can help

Comment: echo "I just pull this from ".$domain." from ".$time; use this

Comment: Are you trying to output the MySQL query string to display the names of the variables you are passing in?

Comment: yes @ScottHelme the variables is already within my mysql column... i just want to echo it and display the variables already assigned at the top

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the next string in,

```
$result = "I just pull this from '$domain' from '$time'";
```

I am adding single quotes so that you would learn to use the query string with php variables between single quotes. It's a good practice to prevent SQLi.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do like this.

```
$domain = "test.com";
$time = "12345";

echo "I just pull this from ".$domain." from ".$time;
```